# Simple Javascript show div function isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have the following Javascript function:

```
function checkConnection() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php_scripts/checkconnection.php',
        type: "POST",
        success: function() {
            document.getElementById('openOfflineDIV').style.display = 'none';
            console.log("connected");
        },
        error: function() {
            document.getElementById('openOfflineDIV').style.display = 'block';
            //I have also tried: 
            document.getElementById('openOfflineDIV').style.display = 'inline';
            console.log("disconnected");
        }
    }).complete(function() {
        setTimeout(checkConnection, 1000);
    });
}
```

This function's purpose is to check the internet connectivity status every second. If the connection is active, then the div `openOfflineDIV` should not be visible, but if the connection is lost, then the div should be visible.

This code is partially working, meaning that if I navigate to my webpage address with "/#openOfflineDIV" added to the end of the url, then the page will load with the div showing on screen, this then disappears after a second once the function starts to run (which means the function is closing the div successfully once it realises the connection is active).

But the second part of the function isn't working, it's not displaying the div automatically when the internet connection is lost. I've tried both the inline and block methods but neither is working. I'm very confused since the function is definitely able to hide the div successfully (which I think means my syntax for defining the div is correct).

This is the code for the modal in my html:

```
<div id="openOfflineDIV" class="modalOfflineDIVDialog">
  <div id="mfs">
      <div id="wrapper">
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                       <td align="center" valign="middle" class="alerttextbig">You have been disconnected from the internet!</td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS for the modal:

```
.modalOfflineDIVDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 11;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalOfflineDIVDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalOfflineDIVDialog > div {
    width: 760px;
    height: 545px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1% auto;
}
```

As I said the function is half working, the console.logs `"connected"` and `"disconnected"` are appearing in the console correctly, and it is able to close the div successfully, but I can't figure out why it won't show the div automatically when the internet connection is lost.

Any ideas on why this isn't working fully would be really appreciated.

Comment: are you loading jquery from cdn?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Ajax - How to Detect Network Connection error when making Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730692/jquery-ajax-how-to-detect-network-connection-error-when-making-ajax-call)

Comment: Hi @lal I have ``https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js`` included inside my page's head. Is this bad practice?

Comment: @Emily while offline, you wont be able to load jquery if you use this..try this after downloading jquery and use the path of the downloaded jquery to load it.

Comment: @Emily: It works just fine. See: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/46ujyu0y/ Check by disconnecting and re-connecting.

Comment: also try `cache: false` inside the ajax call

Comment: Hi @lal I uploaded ``jquery-1.11.3.min.js`` to my server and included it in the head of my page but unfortunately it's still performing the same as before.

Comment: @RohitKumar Hi, thanks for your reply. I added ``cache: false`` to the ajax call but it hasn't fixed the problem unfortunately.

Comment: @Emily show us your CSS please

Comment: Hi @MysterX thanks for your comment, I've added the CSS to my question.

Comment: @Emily: Did you take a look at the fiddle I shared in the [above comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561769/simple-javascript-show-div-function-isnt-working#comment52979696_32561769)?

Comment: @Emily, also try to open browser dev-tools and look for this div in the page elements. You can watch does your `display:block` was applied.

Comment: Hi @Abhitalks thanks for your reply and the fiddle. I've tried to implement it, but I'm unsure of what to put in the get request instead of ``'/echo/json/'`` as that doesn't seem to work, I entered the address of a file on my the server instead but it doesn't seem to be working, the console.log just logs the GET attempt every second whether the connection is active or not. I think I may be testing this wrong, what address should I try? Thanks again.

Comment: @Emily: In the fiddle, you cannot change the url because it will be rejected  for cors. In your own code, make the url any page on your website/app and it will work.

Comment: @Emily do you have that problem alive (online)?? I mean do you have a website in which this problem is occuring? if so then share the url..

Comment: Hi @RohitKumar thanks for your comment, I just got this problem resolved, it turned out to be an issue with the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS to hidden block added property `opacity:0` so you need to change it to 1 if you want to see that division when changing `display` property

Comment: Hi @mysterx thanks for your comment! I updated the opacity in the CSS in my question. The function is now working fully! There's one problem though, the div now appears visible at the start of the page loading, it stays on screen for about 5 seconds until everything else is loaded, it then disappears, is there anyway to have it load in the background, out of sight, so that the user doesn't see it when all the page elements are in the process of loading? Thanks again!

Comment: You should make this div hidden by default. Set in CSS `display:none;` for it

Comment: Hi @mysterx thanks for your comment, it turns out that the issue was indeed the CSS! Thanks so much again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$('#openOfflineDIV').hide();` to hide

and this

`$('#openOfflineDIV').show();` to show!

Comment: Hi @sunil thanks for your reply, I originally tried that method, but it didn't work, the console.logs wrote correctly, but the div show-hide methods didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code to show/hide instead of `style.display`:

```
$('#openOfflineDIV').show();
$('#openOfflineDIV').hide();
```

Comment: Hi @rk3024 thanks for your reply, that was the method I originally tried, but it didn't work for me, the console.logs wrote correctly, but the div show-hide didn't work.

Comment: Try this then , to show document.getElementById("remember").style.visibility = "visible"; and to hide document.getElementById("remember").style.visibility = "hidden";