# How do I detect using jquery if a server firewall like mod_security is blocking the jquery ajax from connecting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

Say if I have a situation like this.

[image: firewall blocking website]

How do I detect that with jquery ajax. It hangs on connecting and there is no HTTP Status Code, and no ajax error detected because the file exists.

I have tried using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730692/jquery-ajax-how-to-detect-network-connection-error-when-making-ajax-call) and using `error: function(XMLHttpRequest, status, message){ }` and using `statusCode: { }` feature of jquery ajax it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, impossible.

Comment: @cojack Why is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question with good answer here:

[JQuery Ajax - How to Detect Network Connection error when making Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730692/jquery-ajax-how-to-detect-network-connection-error-when-making-ajax-call)

In short, you can check the "readyState" like:

```
error: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
    if (XMLHttpRequest.readyState == 0) {
        // Network error (Connection refused, Access denied, etc.)
    }
    else {
        // some other error (HTTP error, etc...)
    }
}
```

Here is a full working example for my cases:

```
var params = {name: 'John doe', age: 23};

// Make POST request to the server
$.post('/some/url/to/post', params, function (response) {
    if (!response.result) {
        // I have custom response format - contains validation errors, etc... Sample below:
        //var content = $.isPlainObject(response) ? response.message : response;
        //alert(content, 'Error saving data: Details' + content);
    }
    else {
        // All is fine and data is saved
    }
}).fail(function(jqXHR) {
    var errorMessage = jqXHR.readyState == 0 || !jqXHR.responseText
        ? 'Network error - please check your internet connection or firewalls'
        : jqXHR.responseText;

    alert('Error saving data: Details' +  errorMessage + );
});
```

Comment: I have added to my answer a working example that I use, a bit cleaned of cource